# Most convenient way to store, define and read objects of a class?

Tags: c#, object

I'm looking for a way to store class objects, with specified properties and then read those. This is the approach I've come with:

```
internal class Zones
{
    public Dictionary<string, Zone> zoneData = new Dictionary<string, Zone>()
    {
        { "Something", new Zone() }
    };

    public Zone Load(string zoneName)
    {
        return zoneData[zoneName];
    }
}

internal class Zone
{
    public uint id;
    public string name;
}
```

Then read:

```
Zone z = Zones.Load("Something");
// z.id, z.name
```

But there's a problem. I want to be able to already have multiple `Zone` classes inside that `zoneData` dictionary with properties I've specified.

I thought of couple of options. When main class runs, define new and `zoneData.add(new Zone([Properties]))`. Or directly as I shown at example, but I would have to define those outside and then just add reference.

Again, to this idea all together, what would be the best approach? Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you're trying to reinvent the wheel here.  Are you looking to dynamically load classes at runtime?  If so, look into reflection.  Are you trying to persist the data and structure of classes?  If so, look into serialization.

Comment: Ok maybe I wasn't clear enough, but basically what would be the best way to store Zone class inside dictionary straight on. Without having to Add() those at start of runtime?

Comment: you could persist those using Serialization, then read them in on startup

Comment: You could use object initialization.  For instance, `Dictionary<string, Zone> zoneDate = new Dictionary<string, Zone>() { { "something", new Zone() }, { "somethingelse", new Zone() }};`.  But if you need to add stuff later, you'll have to use `Add()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a constructor for the zones class that creates the classes and puts them in the dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, Zone> m_dict = new ....;
public Zones()
{
  m_dict.Add("zone1", new Zone{id = 42, name = "foo"});
  m_dict.Add("zone2", new Zone{id = 43, name = "bar"});
....
}
```